# Return Index Position

Tags: python, python-3.x

Coming from PHP background, I am learning how to use Python.

I am trying to return Index Position if content are found in the `haystack` from `needle`

```
haystack= open("haystack.wav",'r')
needle = open("needle.wav",'r')
nedOffset = needle.read()[:46]

print(haystack.index(nedOffset))
```

It don't seem to work, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(haystack.index(ned[:46]))
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'index'
```

How to fix?

In PHP I would do:

```
$needle = file_get_contents("needle.wav", false, null, 46);
$haystack = file_get_contents("heystack.wav");
echo strpos($haystack,$needle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read in the string from `haystack`, not just `needle`. Something like:

```
haystack= open("haystack.wav",'r').read()
```

or

```
with open("haystack.wav",'r') as inf:
    haystack = inf.read()
```

Comment: Oops. totally forgot about the haystack

Comment: Now I am getting different error: `File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 5: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: That's an entirely different problem that would necessitate a different question. (Furthermore, that can't be your full traceback since it doesn't show what line it occurs on).